# Industrial Raspberry PI with portainer.io: file permission issues, app dumped

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, portainer

I've built an image (docker buildx) from an ubuntu 18, stored to tar, uploaded on Portainer (running on RPI)

Using Portainer, I create a stack with yaml file, and I get a "deployment error", but the container is created

Below, the composer file content:

```
version: '2'
services:
    sda:
        image: <out image>
        network_mode: "host"
        container_name: "sda4"
        volumes:
          - virtual_sda4:/opt/<company>/<application>
        stdin_open: true
```

Running the container our app is dumped.
Connecting with console as root user, listing files has a strange result:
all files have "undefined" permissions (question marks instead of rwx)
It seems a permission issue.

(*) stdin_open: true: used to keep alive the container, because the app is dumped.

Any idea is appreciated
Thanks
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this topic. The problem was linked to different docker version used for building and deploying the images. The builder was 20.*, the version on RPI was 18.*. Updating the version on RPI, provided by the board integratori, solved the issue.

Hoping this is useful to others.
Lorenzo